# Calculating number of rows in a table within a separate workbook

Tags: excel, object, copying, vba

I initially had a table within a worksheet "1" called "table". From within this workbook I could use the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
                latestSequenceNumber = 7
                MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)
                latestSequenceNumber = Worksheets("1").ListObjects("table").Range.Row.Count 
                MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)          
End Sub
```

The above worked.

I have now moved the sheet with the table in to a new, separate workbook called "testLocation.xlsx" residing within the same folder. Hence, I have now been attempting to use this code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set repo = Workbooks.Open("testLocation.xlsx")
               latestSequenceNumber = 7
                MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)
                latestSequenceNumber = repo.Worksheets("1").ListObjects("table").Range.Row.Count 'object required error?!
                MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)                
End Sub
```

Any ideas as to why this is throwing an 'Object required' error and/or how to resolve this?

Comment: In your new workbook, do you still have a table defined and named `table1`?

Comment: This `Set repo = Workbooks.Open("testLocation.xlsx")` must include the full path of the file to open it, not just the workbook name.

Comment: The book opens w/o the full file path. Will try however and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The new workbook has a table named table indeed. Sheet is called 1 and table "table"

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set repo = Workbooks.Open("testLocation.xlsx")
    latestSequenceNumber = 7
    MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)
    latestSequenceNumber = repo.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("table").Range.Rows.Count 'object required error?!
    MsgBox (latestSequenceNumber)
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what is wrong on your side as you missed "s" in your code example. You want Range.Rows not Range.Row.Count.

Comment: If this sheet is first sheet in workbook it will work. If you need reference to name, put it in quotes.